# media query working on chrome but not on mobile

Tags: html, css

this is a piece of my CSS:

```css
@media (max-width: 800px) {

    body {
        background:black;
        background-image:none;
        font-size:30px;
    }

    #logo {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }
    .mobile {
        display: inline;
        align-content: center;
        font-size:60px;
    }
    .longtext {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

On chrome, when I resize the window it changes to the setting i wanted to, but when going to devtools responsive check or visiting on mobile, it just doesn't work. Not a single setting.

heeeelp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add this meta tag in `<head></head>`. [More information from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```