# How do I make this media query functional?

Tags: html, css

> I tried to use the `CSS media query` in order to give my website a little responsiveness(it's just kinda prototyping though)but the media query isn't working. All I wanted was to make the `container` disappear.

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.container
{
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #494d5f;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 300px 300px 300px;
}
.container>div
{
    border: 2px solid green;
    color: white;
    font-size: 40px;

}
.container>:last-child
{
    margin-right: 0;
}
span
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Wallpaper Carousel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="first">1</div>
                <div class="second"><span class="before">a</span>1<span class="after">b</span></div>
                <div class="third">3</div>
            
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [media query working on chrome but not on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094445/10698741)

Comment: Damn it dude, It worked. Thanks.