# why mobile responsive design does not work

Tags: html, css, frontend

I am new to css and try to learn responsive design. But my code does not work correctly.In mobile/tablet size it is looking like it is a pc screen. What is the problem?

[Iphone x screen](https://hizliresim.com/zLoRdb)

```css
#navbar {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:768)" href="css/tablet.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:500)" href="css/mobile.css">

<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav id="navbar">
      <h1></h1>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#home"> anasayfa</a></li>
        <li><a href="#training"> eğitimler</a></li>
        <li><a href="#courses"> dersler</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact"> iletişim</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [media query working on chrome but not on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62094445/10698741)

Comment: ı have this meta tag

Comment: share your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [link media attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-media)

> This attribute specifies the media that the linked resource applies to. Its value must be a media type / media query.

The media queries in the `media` attribute of your `<link>`s are not valid, as the widths need units. eg:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width:768px)" href="css/tablet.css">`

[image: Edit affectionate-field-tn957]